# Got error when trying to use promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise

Trying to use promise on node pg module as in the [module page](https://node-postgres.com/), but got errors. Any comments are appreciated.

Here is the code `pg1.js`

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client= new Client({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1',
  database: 'staging'
})
await client.connect()
console.log("connected")

x = await client.query("select * from phaas_global.organization")
console.log("x=")
console.log(x)
```

Here are the error when running on my Mac.

```
$ node pg1.js
/Users/user/learn/node/pg1.js:9
await client.connect()
      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
MSS1:node user$ node -v
v7.5.0
```

**UPDATE1**
I changed the code to the following, still get error.

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

async connect() {
    const client= new Client({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      user: 'phaasuser',
      password: 'phaaspass',
      database: 'phaas_staging'
    })


    await client.connect()
    console.log("connected")

    x = await client.query("select * from phaas_global.organization")
    console.log("x=")
    console.log(x)
}
```

Here is the error

$ node pg1.js

```
/Users/user/learn/node/pg1.js:3
async connect() {
      ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
```

Comment: 1) You should first learn about promises and proper use of `async/await`, because they are out of place in your code 2) Then move on to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which makes far better use of promises and asynchronous architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` operator can only be used inside an `async` function:

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for more info:

```
async function main() {
    const client = new Client({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        user: 'user1',
        password: 'pass1',
        database: 'staging'
    })
    await client.connect()
    console.log("connected")

    x = await client.query("select * from phaas_global.organization")
    console.log("x=")
    console.log(x)
}
```

Or you can wrap it inside an async IIFE:

```
(async() => {
    // This will be immediately called.
    /*...*/
    await client.connect();
    /* ... */
})();
```

Note that async/await shipped in node 7.6.

**Working example** (Must use a browser with async/await support, like Chrome)

```js
(async() => {
    // This will be immediately called.
    /*...*/
    const response = await Promise.resolve('I support async/await');
    console.log(response);
    /* ... */
})();
```

Comment: Thanks @marcos-casagrande, I still get error, see `update1`.

Comment: Check my uptaded answer, I wrote that function using object/class method syntax. add `function` keyword, or use the IIFE

Comment: I tried it but still get error, it complained that the second open paren in `(async() => {` is unexpected.  Wonder if my node v7.5 supports this stuff. Should I update to a newer node.js?

Comment: Node.js 7.6 shipped with official support for async/await. You should update :). I would update to node 8 which is LTS.

Comment: After updated my node.js (from 7.5 to 9.11.1) and it works. Thanks!